# Pyspark : RDD and "WHERE" operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning How to handle `Spark RDD` with Python and I don't find solution according to `rdd.filter()` with `where` condition.

I have a CSV file which looks like this :

```py
id,firstname,city,age,job,salary,childen,awards
1, Yves, OLS-ET-RINHODES, 55, Pilote de chasse, 3395, 3, 3
2, Paul, MARTOT, 32, Pilote d'helicoptere, 2222, 4, 5
3, Steve, DIEULEFIT, 53, Navigateur aerien, 2152, 3, 2
4, Valentin, FEUILLADE, 27, Pilote de chasse, 1776, 0, 2
...
```

And this is my python script :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

#Context properties
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Aeroport")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

#Data Reading
data = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:9000/testfile.csv")

#Split each column
dataset = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))

#Search children number by city
nbChildByCity = dataset.map(lambda row : (row[2],1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)

print "Nombre enfant par ville naissance : " + str(nbChildByCity.collect())

#Search children number by city with father > 50 years old
nbChildByCityFather = dataset.filter(lambda row : row[3] > 50 in nbChildByCity)
#nbChildByCityFather = dataset.filter(lambda row : row[3] > 50 in row[1]) 

print "Nombre enfant par ville naissance avec père > 50 ans : " + str(nbChildByCityFather.collect())
```

**My issue is : #Search children number by city with father > 50 years old**

I don't overcome to add the last condition : `father > 50 years old`. How I have to write `where` condition into RDD ?

I tried this :

```py
nbChildByCityFather = dataset.filter(lambda row : row[3] > 50 in nbChildByCity)
nbChildByCityFather = dataset.filter(lambda row : row[3] > 50 in row[1])
```

But none result ..

Comment: nbChildByCityFather = nbChildByCity.filter(lambda row : row[3] > 50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier and more efficiently implemented using the data frame API (see alternative approach at the bottom).

To get the number of entries where age in row is over 50, you first need to filter. You also need to use the age column (index 6) in your `reduce` call:

Number of children by city:

```
nbChildByCity = data.map(lambda row : (row[2], int(row[6].strip()))) 
                     #note that it's using child count, not 1

nbChildByCity.collect()
```

Outputs:

```
[(' OLS-ET-RINHODES', 3), (' MARTOT', 4), (' DIEULEFIT', 3), (' FEUILLADE', 0)]
```

Same, but wi:

```
nbChildByCity50 = rdd.filter(lambda l: int(l[3]) > 50 )\
                     .map(lambda row : (row[2], int(row[6].strip()) ))\
                     .reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
print("Nombre enfant par ville naissance :" + str(nbChildByCity50.collect()))
```

Outputs:

```
Nombre enfant par ville naissance :[(' OLS-ET-RINHODES', 3), (' DIEULEFIT', 3)]
```

**Note that it's easier and more appropriate to do this using the data frame API:**

```
df = spark.read.csv('cities.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
grp = df.groupBy(['city'])
grp.sum('childen').show()
```

Which gives:

```
+----------------+------------+
|            city|sum(childen)|
+----------------+------------+
|       FEUILLADE|         0.0|
|          MARTOT|         4.0|
|       DIEULEFIT|         3.0|
| OLS-ET-RINHODES|         3.0|
+----------------+------------+
```

And with a filter by age:

```
grp = df.where('age > 50').groupBy(['city'])
grp.sum('childen').show()
```

Which outputs:

```
+----------------+------------+
|            city|sum(childen)|
+----------------+------------+
|       DIEULEFIT|         3.0|
| OLS-ET-RINHODES|         3.0|
+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: If I would like to use Spark in order to make this kind of things, what is better : RDD or Dataframe ?
Both are using cluster nodes ? There is a faster approach ?

Comment: Data frames are a higher-level API using RDDs underneath. It all depends on the functionality you need to reach, but favor data frames. Also good to note that data frames and RDDs are interoperable... Check the SQL/RDD documentation page, it's explained in details!

Comment: Yes I knew the duality between RDD/Dataframes ;) And both used cluster nodes in order to execute jobs right ?

Comment: Oh yes! Both use Spark's distributed compute engine, running on cluster nodes as usual

Comment: Ok perfect ! Thank you very much ! It's not easy when someone begins with Spark and the distributed environment but I understand well dataframes and syntax is easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should *`filter` first* *before you apply the `reduceByKey`*

```
nbChildByCityFather = dataset.filter(lambda row : int(row[3].strip()) > 50).map(lambda row : (row[2],1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
print "Nombre enfant par ville naissance avec pere > 50 ans : " + str(nbChildByCityFather.collect())
```

**Note: this method only works if you remove the header line from the csv file or somehow filter it.**